# Custom Template in phpDocumentor ( Failed to create "phar:.......)

Tags: templates, symfony, phpdoc

I had made a custom template (extended from `responsiv-twig`) for phpDocumentor a year ago.

Now with the new Version of phpDocumentor, I can't use this.

I also tried out to copy a clean  (`responsive-twig`) template from `phpDocumentor.phar` to an directory. I become in both cases following error Message:

```
Preparing template "/Users/rov/Documents/phpStorm/phpDocNewTemplat .. 


  [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]                                                                                                                                                    
  Failed to create "phar:///Users/rov/Documents/phpStorm/IA_Local_Development_Instance_Symfony_3/docs/phpDoc/phpDocumentor.phar/src/phpDocumentor/Transformer/../../../data/templates/phpDocNewTemplate"
```

Same issue if I try generating the docs with a gulp.

I tried out:

- `chmod -R 777 on my own template folder` (nothing changed)
- `chmod -R 777 on my phpDocumentor folder` (nothing changed)
- use the original template with: `--template=responsive-twig` (works)
- googled the problem (nothing helpfull found)

This is my terminal command:

```
php docs/phpDoc/phpDocumentor.phar -d ./src -t ./docs/phpDoc --template="/Users/rov/Documents/phpStorm/phpDocNewTemplate" --title=MyTitle
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like phpDocumentor is intended for Symfony2 projects:
https://packagist.org/packages/phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor

I tried it on my host and it doesn't work with Symfony3 and PHP7.

I would suggest using Sami:
https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Sami

I tried it and it seems simple to use. It has themes as well, and this is supported in Symfony3 as the Symfony3 uses this to generate their own documentation.

Comment: Without a custom template phpDoc works fine with symfony (php 5.5.36)

I will looking @Sami.

It would be nice, if phpDoc would work, because the other projects are no symfony projects and i would like to have one documentor for all :)

Answer (score -1):

The bug is only phpDocumentor phar.

With this version I have no problem. I can create my own template and this run fine.

[phpDocumentor-2.9.0.tgz](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/releases/download/v2.9.0/phpDocumentor-2.9.0.tgz)